# Unexpected result when drawing bmp from buffer

Tags: c, bitmap, rendering, bmp

The last time i had problem with this was because i swapped `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` in the wrong way. After that i have been told for correct way and i fixed it. However.. today i noticed that the function isn't working as it was expected on some bmp images.

[image: Comparement:]

I am rendering the image from a buffer that has all the image's byte data.
And there is the function to render:

```
void bmp_bdraw (BYTE* BUFF)
{

    word WIDTH, HEIGHT, W, H; // word - unsigned short
    BYTE R, G, B; // BYTE - unsigned char

    (!BUFF || !BUFF[COUNT-1]) ? // debug1
        (error("Error in function 'bmp_bdraw'. There is no data to read from.")) : ;                  

    WIDTH = BUFF[18] + BUFF[19] * 256;
    HEIGHT = BUFF[22] + BUFF[23] * 256;
    ofs = 54;

    if(BUFF[0] != 'B' | BUFF[1] != 'M') error // debug2
        ("Warning: Data identifier error in function 'bmp_bdraw' occurred. Invalid BMP file loaded.");

    for(H=HEIGHT-1; H>=0; H--)
    {
        for(W=0; W<WIDTH; W++)
        {
            B = sgetc(BUFF); // fgetc-like function but from buff
            G = sgetc(BUFF);
            R = sgetc(BUFF);

            setpen(R, G, B, 0, 1); // sets the color, transparancy and size of the pen
            putpixel(W, H); // and puts the pixel at the right location
        }
    }

    if(W != WIDTH || H > 1) // debug3
        error("Error in function 'bmp_bdraw'. Rendering failed. The file might be damaged.");         

    if(real_fps < 11)
        error("Too low fps rate."); // debug4
}
```

Comment: Whats going wrong? That cross line in output image?

Comment: @Mr.32 Look at the image in right. It looks awful. Thats not how the output should look like.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong parametrically. That should be in functionality understanding. It will be more on setpen()

Comment: @Mr.32 Well im using the same function on `bmp_ddraw()` which renders the image directly. From file stream to area. And there are no problems using this method.

Comment: Does both has same pixel rendering order? I mean here you are rendering from H(max) to H(0) and w(0) to w(max)

Comment: @Mr.32 Yes, both functions uses the same method.

Comment: This really, really, *really* looks like you still do not understand what "padding" is for. Please go back to your previous questions on this topic and re-read the comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data here (BUFF buffer) is correct then
I am sharing my observation with you so you can debug further more.

You are rendering from (H(max),w(0)) to (H(0),w(max)). So in beging everything is good. Image is good but when your H(max) get decrease output image gets bad.

In simple term in bottom part of image output is good when in top part output is bad. It seems like pixel get strinked in top part.

I do not understand how setpen() works. and after processing you should paint that pixel at same position or not?

I think As H(max) decrease with that you should decrease your W value in `putpixel(W, H);` I think this will remove that inclined vertical line and bad image issue.

Comment: `setpen` just sets the color, transperancy and size of the "pen" in real time.
Don't mind it. I am curious why the image is rendered correct when using the direct method.. but when using the draw_fbuff..